# Prove that $n+2$ points in $\Bbb R^n$ cannot all be at a unit distance from each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I saw this on the FB group "Actually good math problems" where one solution was an illegible photo and the other involved intersecting spheres. I have a solution. I'd like to see how many good answers I get before I post it.

If $S$ is a set of $n+2$ points in $\Bbb R^n$ (with $n\in \Bbb N$) with the usual (Cartesian) norm, show there exist $2$ distinct $p,q\in S$ with $\|p-q\|\ne 1.$

Comment: This question has appeared here before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622936/proof-maximum-number-of-equidistant-points-for-a-given-dimension) for instance.  Note that that question is itself a duplicate.

Comment: @lulu:  that one and the one it links to show the existence of $n+1$ points in $\Bbb R^n$, but do not prove you cannot do $n +2$

Comment: @RossMillikan [This answer does](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2623156).

Comment: @RossMillikan  Well, they certainly claim to.  See point $3$ in the top answer.  Are you saying that the given argument is in error?

Comment: @RossMillikan The answer in the linked question shows that if you could do $n+2$, there would be $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. That seems like a proof to me.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. Looks rather long. WLOG the origin belongs to $S$ and if all the other points in $S\setminus \{0\}$ are unit vectors at distance $1$ from each other, they are linearly independent (which doesn't depend on $|S|$).

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $\{P_1,\ldots,P_{n+2}\}$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|P_i-P_j\|=1$ for any $i\neq j$.
We may assume without loss of generality that $P_{n+2}=O$. From the polarization formula
$$ 2\cos\theta_{ij}=2\langle P_i, P_j \rangle = \|P_i-P_j\|^2 + \|P_i+P_j\|^2 = 1+\|P_i+P_j\|^2\geq 1$$
it follows that $\widehat{P_i O P_j}\geq \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\langle P_i,P_j\rangle \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for any $i\neq j$ such that $i,j\in{1,\ldots,n+1}$. We have

$$ n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\|P_{n+1}-P_k\|^2=2n-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle P_k,P_{n+1}\rangle \leq n$$
holding as a strict inequality unless $\langle P_{n+1},P_k\rangle=\frac{1}{2}$ for any $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. This implies that $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ all lie 
on a affine hyperplane $\pi$, while $P_{n+1}$ and $P_{n+2}$ lie on opposite sides of it, since $\langle P_{n+1},P_{n+1}\rangle = 1, \langle P_{n+1},P_{n+2}\rangle=0$. These equalities give that $O=P_{n+2}$ and $P_{n+1}$ are  actually symmetric with respect to $\pi$. Let $M\in \pi$ be the midpoint of $P_{n+1} P_{n+2}$. By the Pythagorean theorem $P_k M=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ for any $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so we have $n$ points, $1$-apart from each other, on a $S^{n-2}$ with radius $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\simeq \pi$. Let us consider $P_1$ and $P_2$: all the points $P_3,\ldots,P_n$ have to lie on the previous sphere *and* on the spheres centered at $P_1,P_2$ with unit radius. These spheres do not have a common intersection, so we cannot have $n+2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are $1$-apart from each other.

Comment: If $\|P_i-P_j\|=1$ whenever $i\ne j,$ and $P_{n+2}=O,$ then $\|P_i\|=\|P_i-P_{n+2}\|=1$ when $i<n+2$. So when $i<j<n+2$ we have $1=\|P_i-P_j\|^2=2-2<P_i,P_j>,$ implying $<P_i,P_j>=1/2.$

Comment: My answer, if this were not a duplicate Q, is the one in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30270/maximum-number-of-mutually-equidistant-points-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean-spac     which I found thanks to a comment to this Q