# Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $0 \in X$ and $\|x-y\| = 1$ for $x,y \in X, x \neq y$. Then the maximum number of elements in $X$ is $n+1$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $0 \in X$ and $\|x-y\| = 1$ for $x,y \in X, x \neq y$. Then the maximum number of elements in $X$ is $n+1$.

**My attempt**

By contradiction, let's suppose that $X$ has more than $n+1$ elements.
Then, take $x_0 = 0$, and $x_1,...,x_{n+1}\in X$.

I realized the following:

$\|x\| = 1$ for all $x\in X-\{0\}.$

$\|x_i-x_j\|^2 = \langle\,x_i-x_j,x_i-x_j\rangle = 1$ $\Rightarrow$
$\langle\, x_i,x_j\rangle = 1/2 $ if $i\neq j.$

And I'm stuck here.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30270/maximum-number-of-mutually-equidistant-points-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean-spac. I think I saw an answer on MSE as well, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: Perhaps this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60856/a-sphere-containing-points-of-pairwise-equal-distance

Comment: I dk if this will help.Translate the set of points so that one of them is the origin. Can we show that the others are linearly independent?

Comment: I don't know the details well enough, but can a direct induction proof work? It definitely describes the rigidity of there being only one extra point each time to me (because the other possible point is going to be more than one unit away from the first extra one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{x_0=0,x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$, with $\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert=1$ if $i\ne j$. It follows that $\Vert x_i\Vert=1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=\dfrac12$ for distinct $i\ne j$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. 
We want to prove that $m\le n$. Clearly we may suppose that $m>1$, because if $m=1$ there is nothing to prove.

Now, let $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^mx_i$. Clearly we have
$$\eqalign{ \Vert v\Vert^2 &=m+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}=\frac{m(m+1)}{2},\tag{1}\cr
\langle x_i,v\rangle&=\frac{m+1}{2},\qquad\hbox{for $i=1,2,\ldots,m$.}  }$$
For a given real $t$ (to be determined later), we consider $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m$ defined by $y_i=tx_i-v$.
Using $(1)$ we have, for $i\ne j$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$:
$$\eqalign{\Vert y_i\Vert^2&=t^2-2t\frac{m+1}{2}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}
\cr
&=(t-\frac{m+1}{2})^2+\frac{m^2-1}{2}>0.\cr
\langle y_i,y_j\rangle&=\frac{1}{2}t^2-2t\frac{m+1}{2}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\cr
&=\frac{(t-m-1)^2-m-1}{2}
}$$
Now, choosing $t=m+1+\sqrt{m+1}$, we see that $\langle y_i,y_j\rangle=0$ for every $i,j$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ with $i\ne j$. Therefore $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m)$ is a system of orthogonal non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$,they are linearly independent and consequently $m\le n$, that is
$\vert X\vert=m+1\le n+1$,which is the desired conclusion.